# Magento to Accounting systems

Tags: extensions, third-party-module

we use Magento Community version 1.8.0.0 (now Magento users for since several years). We and our members need to connect to our respective Accounting systems to facilitate the accounting procedures. Now it is a bit tedious to manually book invoices in the Accounting system. I would be happy to have your suggestions on which extensions/bridges to use. As we are based in Sweden it would be great if we could find solutions to Accounting system that are used here.
Of course more generally it would be interesting to hear how this demand is handled around the world.

Answer (score 1):

There are various options around. i suggest you look on the magento connect site for the extensions available, they all have their own workflow.

In its simplest form you could use an invoice export\import model. plenty do that currently.

Answer (score 1):

Magento is a weird non GAAP standard package that often has severe mismatches in the way it understands accounting as opposed to the way that reality based GAAP standard ERP systems handle accounting.

You have two ways of handling it:

1. Go with order import/export
2. Find developers that are primarily experienced with your ERP system and secondarily develop for Magento and then ask them for demonstrable work already done in integrating to see how well they've handled it. The results are highly variable, so you will have to find software developers that work the way you want to work.

All the promised ERP connectors of long ago were vaporware and evaporated when the reality of the first paragraph became apparent about 2 years into everyone adopting Magento.

Helps if you're a major corporation with an experienced e-commerce team with a budget and outside help from people who've done it and not just only promised it.